# How to add folders in the main folder in webscripts

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

i need your help, I have created in Share a new type folder, called "TanFolder". it's on documentLibrary.  I would like, when i create this folder, three other folders will be created  automatically within it

Example:     every time i create a TanFolder three folders will be automatically created in this tanFolder

the problem is that, I do not know where I need to make code changes

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Several approaches are possible. It depends on the use case.

You can use **space templates**. These are defined in Data dictionary/Space templates and can be added in any site using the Create button in the toolbar. Just create a folderstructure once inside the space templates folder and you can reuse it every time. No code changes needed.

Or you can create a custom **Rule** for your new content type which executes a javascript that creates the subfolders every time a new TanFolder is created. Would require just a small javascript. The rest is condiguration.

A third approach is to use **Alfresco Behaviours**. This requires some java code and a bean declaration. If you are starting with Alfresco I would try the first two approaches first.

Comment: Some links:
http://docs.alfresco.com/cloud/tasks/library-folder-rules-define-create.html  
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/space-nodes-create.html
http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/references/dev-extension-points-behaviors.html

Comment: thank you very much, Nick i used the first approach, because i don't know where i have to add javaScript code, i mean, if i want to edit something (in the share plateform) where did i put the code ? is it in the folder site-webscripts ? thank you

Comment: Create a JavaScript file write your logic in it and Put your JavaScript file in Data Dictionary/Scripts folder.